# Bidirectional OneToMany @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I have a problem with LazyCollection.

Guy on this site [lazy collection tutorial](https://sites.google.com/a/pintailconsultingllc.com/java/hibernate-extra-lazy-collection-fetching) says

> Hibernate does not materialize the collection elements when accessing the collection and then inserting into the collection (at least in my example of Winery and Wine OneToMany relationship mapping)

but it doesn't working to me.

Here are my entities:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name="DOCUMENT_GENERATED")
public class DocumentDomainToGenerateImpl extends DomainObjectImpl<DocumentDomainToGenerate, Integer> implements DocumentDomainToGenerate{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1297116626347796196L;
private String identificationKey;
private Identification identification;
private String documentGroup;
private String documentType;
private Server server;
private int statusOrder = 2;
private int numberOfAttempt;
private AuditData auditData;
private Date documentIssuanceDate;
private Date creationDate;
private DocumentStatus documentCurrentState;
private List<DocumentGeneratedHistoryStatus> documentGeneratedHistoryStatusList = new ArrayList<DocumentGeneratedHistoryStatus>(4);



public String getIdentificationKey() {
    return identificationKey;
}

public void setIdentificationKey(String identificationKey) {
    this.identificationKey = identificationKey;
}

@Embedded
@Target(AuditDataImpl.class)
public AuditData getAuditData() {
    return auditData;
}

public void setAuditData(AuditData auditData) {
    this.auditData = auditData;
}

@Embedded
@Target(IdentificationImpl.class)
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "businessId", column = @Column(name = "business_id_doc")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "businessIdContextName", column = @Column(name = "business_id_ctx_doc")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "identificationId", column = @Column(name = "id_doc")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "identificationIdContextName", column = @Column(name = "id_ctx_name_doc")) })
public Identification getIdentification() {
    return identification;
}
public void setIdentification(Identification identification) {
    this.identification = identification;
}
public int getStatusOrder() {
    return statusOrder;
}
public void setStatusOrder(int statusOrder) {
    this.statusOrder = statusOrder;
}

public String getDocumentGroup() {
    return documentGroup;
}
public void setDocumentGroup(String documentGroup) {
    this.documentGroup = documentGroup;
}
public String getDocumentType() {
    return documentType;
}
public void setDocumentType(String documentType) {
    this.documentType = documentType;
}
public int getNumberOfAttempt() {
    return numberOfAttempt;
}
public void setNumberOfAttempt(int numberOfAttempt) {
    this.numberOfAttempt = numberOfAttempt;
}
@Embedded
@Target(ServerImpl.class)
public Server getServer() {
    return server;
}
public void setServer(Server server) {
    this.server = server;
}
@Embedded
@Target(DocumentStatusImpl.class)
public DocumentStatus getDocumentCurrentState() {
    return documentCurrentState;
}

public void setDocumentCurrentState(DocumentStatus documentCurrentState) {
    this.documentCurrentState = documentCurrentState;
}
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getDocumentIssuanceDate() {
    return documentIssuanceDate;
}

public void setDocumentIssuanceDate(Date documentIssuanceDate) {
    this.documentIssuanceDate = documentIssuanceDate;
}
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = DocumentGeneratedHistoryStatusImpl.class)
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "doc_gen_status", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="doc_gen_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "doc_gen_stat_id")})
@IndexColumn(name="doc_gen_id_index", base = 1)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
public List<DocumentGeneratedHistoryStatus> getDocumentGeneratedHistoryStatusList() {
    return documentGeneratedHistoryStatusList;
}

public void setDocumentGeneratedHistoryStatusList(
        List<DocumentGeneratedHistoryStatus> documentGeneratedHistoryStatusList) {
    this.documentGeneratedHistoryStatusList = documentGeneratedHistoryStatusList;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;

    if (!(o instanceof DocumentDomainToGenerateImpl)) return false;

    DocumentDomainToGenerateImpl that = (DocumentDomainToGenerateImpl) o;

    return new EqualsBuilder()
            .appendSuper(super.equals(o))
            .append(getStatusOrder(), that.getStatusOrder())
            .append(getNumberOfAttempt(), that.getNumberOfAttempt())
            .append(getIdentificationKey(), that.getIdentificationKey())
            .append(getIdentification(), that.getIdentification())
            .append(getDocumentGroup(), that.getDocumentGroup())
            .append(getDocumentType(), that.getDocumentType())
            .append(getServer(), that.getServer())
            .append(getAuditData(), that.getAuditData())
            .append(getDocumentIssuanceDate(), that.getDocumentIssuanceDate())
            .append(getCreationDate(), that.getCreationDate())
            .append(getDocumentCurrentState(), that.getDocumentCurrentState())
            .isEquals();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37)
            .appendSuper(super.hashCode())
            .append(getIdentificationKey())
            .append(getIdentification())
            .append(getDocumentGroup())
            .append(getDocumentType())
            .append(getServer())
            .append(getStatusOrder())
            .append(getNumberOfAttempt())
            .append(getAuditData())
            .append(getDocumentIssuanceDate())
            .append(getCreationDate())
            .append(getDocumentCurrentState())
            .toHashCode();
}
```

second entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="DOC_GEN_HIST_STATUS")
public class DocumentGeneratedHistoryStatusImpl extends DomainObjectImpl<DocumentGeneratedHistoryStatus, Integer> implements DocumentGeneratedHistoryStatus{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8542541552897795870L;
private DocumentStatus documentStatus;
private DocumentDomainToGenerate documentDomainToGenerate;
@Embedded
@Target(DocumentStatusImpl.class)
public DocumentStatus getDocumentStatus() {
    return documentStatus;
}

public void setDocumentStatus(DocumentStatus documentStatus) {
    this.documentStatus = documentStatus;
}

@Override
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = DocumentDomainToGenerateImpl.class)
public DocumentDomainToGenerate getDocumentDomainToGenerate() {
    return documentDomainToGenerate;
}
@Override
public void setDocumentDomainToGenerate(DocumentDomainToGenerate documentDomainToGenerate) {
    this.documentDomainToGenerate = documentDomainToGenerate;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;

    if (!(o instanceof DocumentGeneratedHistoryStatusImpl)) return false;

    DocumentGeneratedHistoryStatusImpl that = (DocumentGeneratedHistoryStatusImpl) o;

    return new EqualsBuilder()
            .appendSuper(super.equals(o))
            .append(getDocumentStatus(), that.getDocumentStatus())
            .isEquals();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder(11, 61)
            .appendSuper(super.hashCode())
            .append(getDocumentStatus())
            .toHashCode();
}
```

}

and when i'm loading DocumentDomainToGenerate the following sql is executed:

```
select
    this_.id as id25_0_,
    this_.business_id_app as business2_25_0_,
    this_.business_id_ctx_app as business3_25_0_,
    this_.id_app as id4_25_0_,
    this_.id_ctx_name_app as id5_25_0_,
    this_.moduleName as moduleName25_0_,
    this_.business_id_app_role as business7_25_0_,
    this_.business_id_ctx_app_role as business8_25_0_,
    this_.id_app_role as id9_25_0_,
    this_.id_ctx_name_app_role as id10_25_0_,
    this_.business_id_app_user as business11_25_0_,
    this_.business_id_ctx_app_user as business12_25_0_,
    this_.id_app_user as id13_25_0_,
    this_.id_ctx_name_app_user as id14_25_0_,
    this_.creationDate as creatio15_25_0_,
    this_.doc_stat_app_b_id as doc16_25_0_,
    this_.doc_stat_app_b_id_ctx as doc17_25_0_,
    this_.doc_stat_app_id as doc18_25_0_,
    this_.doc_stat_app_id_ctx as doc19_25_0_,
    this_.doc_stat_app_module_name as doc20_25_0_,
    this_.doc_stat_role_b_id as doc21_25_0_,
    this_.doc_stat_role_b_id_ctx as doc22_25_0_,
    this_.doc_stat_role_id as doc23_25_0_,
    this_.doc_stat_role_id_ctx as doc24_25_0_,
    this_.doc_stat_user_b_id as doc25_25_0_,
    this_.doc_stat_user_b_id_ctx as doc26_25_0_,
    this_.doc_stat_user_id as doc27_25_0_,
    this_.doc_stat_user_id_ctx as doc28_25_0_,
    this_.description as descrip29_25_0_,
    this_.effectiveDateTime as effecti30_25_0_,
    this_.orderToSend as orderTo31_25_0_,
    this_.sended as sended25_0_,
    this_.statusCode_id as statusCode45_25_0_,
    this_.documentGroup as documen33_25_0_,
    this_.documentIssuanceDate as documen34_25_0_,
    this_.documentType as documen35_25_0_,
    this_.business_id_doc as business36_25_0_,
    this_.business_id_ctx_doc as business37_25_0_,
    this_.id_doc as id38_25_0_,
    this_.id_ctx_name_doc as id39_25_0_,
    this_.identificationKey as identif40_25_0_,
    this_.numberOfAttempt as numberO41_25_0_,
    this_.ip as ip25_0_,
    this_.nodePid as nodePid25_0_,
    this_.statusOrder as statusO44_25_0_ 
from
    DOCUMENT_GENERATED this_ 
where
    this_.id = ?
```

next i need to add new DocumentGeneratedHistoryStatus into the list in DocumentDomaintToGenerate and when i'm executing this

```
documentGeneratedHistoryStatus.setDocumentDomainToGenerate(documentDomainToGenerate);
documentDomainToGenerate.getDocumentGeneratedHistoryStatusList().add(documentGeneratedHistoryStatus);
```

this sql is executed

```
select
    documentge0_.doc_gen_id as doc1_25_2_,
    documentge0_.doc_gen_stat_id as doc2_2_,
    documentge0_.doc_gen_id_index as doc3_2_,
    documentge1_.id as id10_0_,
    documentge1_.documentDomainToGenerate_id as documen19_10_0_,
    documentge1_.doc_stat_app_b_id as doc2_10_0_,
    documentge1_.doc_stat_app_b_id_ctx as doc3_10_0_,
    documentge1_.doc_stat_app_id as doc4_10_0_,
    documentge1_.doc_stat_app_id_ctx as doc5_10_0_,
    documentge1_.doc_stat_app_module_name as doc6_10_0_,
    documentge1_.doc_stat_role_b_id as doc7_10_0_,
    documentge1_.doc_stat_role_b_id_ctx as doc8_10_0_,
    documentge1_.doc_stat_role_id as doc9_10_0_,
    documentge1_.doc_stat_role_id_ctx as doc10_10_0_,
    documentge1_.doc_stat_user_b_id as doc11_10_0_,
    documentge1_.doc_stat_user_b_id_ctx as doc12_10_0_,
    documentge1_.doc_stat_user_id as doc13_10_0_,
    documentge1_.doc_stat_user_id_ctx as doc14_10_0_,
    documentge1_.description as descrip15_10_0_,
    documentge1_.effectiveDateTime as effecti16_10_0_,
    documentge1_.orderToSend as orderTo17_10_0_,
    documentge1_.sended as sended10_0_,
    documentge1_.statusCode_id as statusCode20_10_0_,
    documentdo2_.id as id25_1_,
    documentdo2_.business_id_app as business2_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.business_id_ctx_app as business3_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.id_app as id4_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.id_ctx_name_app as id5_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.moduleName as moduleName25_1_,
    documentdo2_.business_id_app_role as business7_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.business_id_ctx_app_role as business8_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.id_app_role as id9_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.id_ctx_name_app_role as id10_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.business_id_app_user as business11_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.business_id_ctx_app_user as business12_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.id_app_user as id13_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.id_ctx_name_app_user as id14_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.creationDate as creatio15_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.doc_stat_app_b_id as doc16_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.doc_stat_app_b_id_ctx as doc17_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.doc_stat_app_id as doc18_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.doc_stat_app_id_ctx as doc19_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.doc_stat_app_module_name as doc20_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.doc_stat_role_b_id as doc21_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.doc_stat_role_b_id_ctx as doc22_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.doc_stat_role_id as doc23_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.doc_stat_role_id_ctx as doc24_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.doc_stat_user_b_id as doc25_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.doc_stat_user_b_id_ctx as doc26_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.doc_stat_user_id as doc27_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.doc_stat_user_id_ctx as doc28_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.description as descrip29_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.effectiveDateTime as effecti30_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.orderToSend as orderTo31_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.sended as sended25_1_,
    documentdo2_.statusCode_id as statusCode45_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.documentGroup as documen33_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.documentIssuanceDate as documen34_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.documentType as documen35_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.business_id_doc as business36_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.business_id_ctx_doc as business37_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.id_doc as id38_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.id_ctx_name_doc as id39_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.identificationKey as identif40_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.numberOfAttempt as numberO41_25_1_,
    documentdo2_.ip as ip25_1_,
    documentdo2_.nodePid as nodePid25_1_,
    documentdo2_.statusOrder as statusO44_25_1_ 
from
    doc_gen_status documentge0_ 
inner join
    DOC_GEN_HIST_STATUS documentge1_ 
        on documentge0_.doc_gen_stat_id=documentge1_.id 
left outer join
    DOCUMENT_GENERATED documentdo2_ 
        on documentge1_.documentDomainToGenerate_id=documentdo2_.id 
where
    documentge0_.doc_gen_id=?
```

Is there any option to don't fetch the whole collection when i'm trying to add a new item to collection? What am i doin'g wrong?